# How to convert all characters to uppercase, except for the last character in PHP

Tags: php, string

I need to convert all characters to uppercase except for the last character in the following string:

```
<?php
    $str = "Hello";

    echo $_str = mb_strtoupper(mb_substr($str, 0, strtolower($str))); 
    ?>
```

Comment: Take tha last one out using substr, convert all to uppercase and attach the last one again.. Should be straightforward with basic string operations.

Comment: Look at what your code does: Your code lowers all of a string, then selects the whole strong (for some reason) and then converts the whole string to upper.

Comment: @Martin That is not true, if `$encoding` is not set, the default encoding will be used which can be changed through a function call or `php.ini`.

Comment: `substr` doesn't know or care about 'characters' (which is unfortunate because of its misleading name) it only cares about "bytes". All strings in PHP are binary safe and `mb_substr` is a version of `substr` that operates on "real" characters instead of bytes. So there _is_ a difference, even if you don't specify a character set (_whatever that means_, by the way).

Comment: You could also use *regex* with [preg_replace_callback](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) for this: [`$str = preg_replace_callback('/(\w*)(\w)/u', function($m) { return mb_strtoupper($m[1]).mb_strtolower($m[2]); }, $str);`](https://3v4l.org/Jv9Xu#v8.2rc3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide the string into the relevant parts, treat them accordingly, and then rejoin.

```php
$str = "Hello";
$parts = mb_str_split($str, mb_strlen($str) - 1);
$out = mb_strtoupper($parts[0]) . mb_strtolower($parts[1]);

var_dump($out);
```

Output:

```
string(5) "HELLo"
```

Comment: Nice and clean solution

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of how you could accomplish this.

```
$str = "Hello";
 
$last_char = substr($str, -1);
$str = substr_replace($str ,"",-1);

$str = strtoupper($str);
$str = $str . $last_char;

echo $str;
```

Where `substr($str, -1);` is grabbing the last character of the string and setting it to `$last_char`.

Where `substr_replace($str ,"",-1)`is replacing the last character from the string with "nothing".

Where `strtoupper($str);` is capitalizing all the characters in the string.

Where `$str . $last_char;` is re-adding the character to the end of the string using concatenation.

OUTPUT:

```
string(5) "HELLo"
```